# Form View OnPageIndexChanging Event  not working

Tags: c#, formview

I have made AllowPaging to True in formview .It is showing the link buttons but they are not working(obviously they need a function to execute).I have OnPageIndexChangeing  event like Below .Can you please tell how to jump to next page and make the pager working.I am bind the Form view using sp in Page_Load event.

Aspx code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="form_view_with_sp" runat="server" OnModeChanging="mode_changeing"     OnPageIndexChanging="page_index_chaging"  AllowPaging="true">
```

page_index_changing event:-

```
 protected void page_index_chaging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Page_Load:-

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    //cmd.CommandText = "selectprocedure";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adb = new SqlDataAdapter("selectprocedure", con);
    form_view_with_sp.DataSource = dt;
    form_view_with_sp.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assign the DataSource of the FormView in the page_index_chaging event handler. Please try to use the following

```
protected void page_index_chaging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["DataSource"];
    form_view_with_sp.DataSource = dt;
    form_view_with_sp.DataBind();
}
```

Remember to put the DataTable into ViewState in Page_Load event when creating the DataSource.

Comment: I am newbie.I didn't get your instruction "Remember to put the DataTable into ViewState in Page_Load event when creating the DataSource.".What it does mean?
I just changed DataSource to "selectprocedure"(SP).

Comment: I mean to say that in Page_Load when create dt, put it into ViewState so that it can be used in page_index_changing event.